# C++ variadic template function ERROR C2672 'no matching overloaded function found'

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

I am currently trying to familiarize myself with variadic templates in c++, but I've kinda run into a wall of some sort, where every recursive implementation gives me error C2672. Even examples I've looked up in videos online and that I've seen work do notfor me for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T sum(T t, Args... args)
{
    return t + sum( args...);
}

template<typename T>
T sum(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 + t2;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Message     could be 'T sum(T,Args...)' Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 4

Error   C2672   'sum': no matching overloaded function found    Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     'T sum(T,Args...)': expects 2 arguments - 0 provided    Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,>(T)' being compiled    Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,int>(T,int)' being compiled Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,int,int>(T,int,int)' being compiled Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,int,int,int>(T,int,int,int)' being compiled Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 6

Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,int,int,int,int>(T,int,int,int,int)' being compiled Exercise Variadics  D:****\Desktop\CPP Dev****\Exercise Variadics\Exercise Variadics\Main.cpp 17

I've made sure that I am using C++20. I tried the same code on online compilers with the same result.

Comment: Are you against using fold expressions?

Comment: @Vivick No I am not against using them (fold expressions work for me btw), I just wanted to learn the recursive method as well and am genuinely perplexed why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler never considers the second overload `sum(T, T)` because that overload isn't visible at the point of `sum(args...)` call.

> return t + sum( args...);

That line asks the compiler to invoke some function with unqualified name `sum`. Hence the compiler has to perform a name lookup to find which function to call here.

Non-ADL lookup will consider only those declarations of `sum()` which are visible at that point of call. The only declaration of `sum()` visible to the compiler at that point is that recursive one. But that declaration requires at least one argument. So once the compiler gets down to zero arguments: `t + sum()`, that declaration no longer matches the call, which is exactly what those error messages are telling:

> 'sum': no matching overloaded function found
> see reference to function template instantiation 'T sum<int,>(T)' being compiled

So basically you should put that terminating overload up front:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T sum(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T sum(T t, Args... args)
{
    return t + sum(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Sarumane, thank you! However it's usually better to wait at least a day before accepting an answer. This way you may solicit other better answers, because regular contributors rarely open a question which is already marked as answered.

Comment: Why not use `if constexpr` to eliminate unnecessary specialization?

Comment: @康桓瑋, sure that's possible too!

Comment: The best mental representation I can give to remember how to do it is "think of packs as the tail of an Haskell list"